# Android: open file dialog

Tags: android, openfiledialog

In my app (simple sd card files browser) i want to open file in the same way thet the standart system files browser do, calling the dialog with list of diffrent applications thet can open or execute this file. I already have file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "standart system files browser" in Android.

Assuming that you know the name and MIME type of the file, you can create an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, using `setDataAndType()` to supply the `Uri` to the file and the MIME type. Then, call `startActivity()` on that `Intent`. If the user has chosen a default activity to apply to this type of file, or if there is only one activity that can view the file, then the activity will start. Otherwise, the user will get a "chooser" to allow a choice from the various possible activities.

Comment: but i get net 04-17 00:15:45.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11795): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///sdcard/1FromPC/media/audio.mp3 typ=mp3 }

Comment: @Ihor: You need to use the proper MIME type. `mp3` is not a proper MIME type.

Comment: Thx! But are there any standart map for file extensions and MIME types?

Comment: @Ihor: Not built in. File extensions are generally meaningless in Android, because files are generally meaningless in Android, because Android (and iOS and other mobile operating systems) try to hide the concept of "files" from users.

Comment: @CommonsWare: That's what i was looking for:'MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("file extension")' thank you))!

Comment: @Ihor: I had not realized that was there. Bear in mind that it will be targeting MIME types of relevance to WebKit, which may or may not map to the sorts of files you have in mind.